# Get exactly text that is write in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a text box for writing messages. I want to show the text that is written in this text-box with in a div. I do it but only text is show but formatting is not means when I write using enter then in preview text is display with each other. Not shown in next line.

```js
function limiter(){
  var tex = document.SendSms.msg.value;
  $(".speech").html(tex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name='SendSms'>
<textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="txtareabox" wrap='physical'  onkeyup="limiter()" required ></textarea>

<div id="mobilescreen">
  <div id="mobiletext">
    <p class="speech">See your preview here.. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to replace the `enter` (`\n`, `\r`, `\n\r` `\r\n`) with a `<br>`, but beware the style is not editable. Other wise you do `var text = "<p>" + textarea.value + "</p>"` and replace `enter` with `</p><p>` and add it `div.innerHTML = text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an aproximation at ypur problem. Think the \n in textarea must be translated to `"<br/>"`.

https://jsfiddle.net/qu0mcsd6/

Here is js code:

```
function addText(){
    var tex = document.SendSms.msg.value;
  tex = tex.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  $(".speech").html(tex);
}
$('#poner').click(addText);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute in the `form` tag is deprecated and should not be used ([cf. spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM)), `id` should be used instead.

```
function limiter() {
  var tex = $("#msg").val(); // get the value of the form input (textarea) and store it in tex variable
  $(".speech").html(tex); // set the value as innerHTML of the element(s) with 'speech' class
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `\n` by `<br>` in the returned value :

```
document.SendSms.msg.value.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
```

**NOTE :** Since you're using jQuery you could define the event inside the js code, and I suggest the use of `input` event instead of `keyup` since it's more efficient when you track user inputs

```
$('#msg').on('input', function(){
    $(".speech").html( $(this).val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>") );
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#msg').on('input', function(){
  $(".speech").html( $(this).val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>") );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="SendSms">

  <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="txtareabox" wrap='physical' required ></textarea>
  and the div in which i want to show my preview:

</form>

<div id="mobilescreen">
  <div id="mobiletext">
    <p class="speech">See your preview here.. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really better to prevent the use of inline `onkeyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `String.replace()` to change the \r\n to `<br>`.
here is how you do it in ES6, just use var instead of const and let for backwards compatibility

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea"); 
const div = document.querySelector("div");
let text = textarea.innerHTML;

text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');

div.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<textarea>
Line 1
line2
line3
</textarea>
<div></div>
```

Comment: In the 1rst line of your answer you forget to use the` ` to escape the `<br/>` code.